# Custom NSView embedded in NSSscrollView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview

Is there a way for a custom NSView to know whether it is embedded in a NSScrollView or not?

I am creating a custom NSView for displaying some content.
 
When my view is placed in a window or another view, its size is fixed and the content is clipped to available size. 
When my view is placed in a NSScrollView its size must be adjusted according to content so it can be scrolled if necessary.
I know I can add a member in my view that specifies the NSScrollView that hosts my view and set this member manually in code, but I was wondering if there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't check the methods of `NSView`?

`@property(readonly, strong) NSScrollView *enclosingScrollView;`

or

`var enclosingScrollView: NSScrollView? { get }`

> The nearest ancestor scroll view that contains the current view.
>
> If the current view is not embedded inside a scroll view, the value of this property is nil. This property does not contain the current view if the current view is itself a scroll view. It always contains an ancestor scroll view.

Comment: To be honest no, I did not think such property exists.