# Notification when custom NSView has been added to a NSScrollView

Tags: nsview, nsscrollview

Following on this question ([Custom NSView embedded in NSSscrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495260/custom-nsview-embedded-in-nssscrollview)), when my custom view is embedded in a NSScrollView using IB, I can detect this in awakeFromNib method and perform the required initialization (I have to setup some scroll notifications).
My problem is when by custom view is added to a NSScrollView from code, setting the scrollview's documentView property. In this scenario is my custom view notified in any way (some NSView method that is called and I can override) or I have to perform my initialization explicitly after my view has been added to the scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `documentView` of the scroll view is a subview of this scroll view and `NSView` has lots of usefull methods. In the chapter "Managing the View Hierarchy":

`viewDidMoveToSuperview`

> Informs the view that its superview has changed (possibly to nil).

`viewDidMoveToWindow`

> Informs the view that it has been added to a new view hierarchy.

When the view is added to a superview, `viewDidMoveToSuperview` is called. But the view could already be inside a view (in a XIB or in code) and this superview could be added to a scroll view. `viewDidMoveToWindow` is called when the view has been added to or removed from a view hierarchy.